# Create MediaSource from AudioPlaybackConnection

Tags: audio, uwp, bluetooth, windows-runtime, avrcp

I'm trying to make my windows computer a valid output for bluetooth audio from my phone. Enabling the actual audio was easy enough using the winrt [AudioPlaybackConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio.audioplaybackconnection?view=winrt-22621), but I'm trying to get metadata working and running into dead ends in the Windows UWP documentation. I'm familiar with the [MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer?view=winrt-22621) class, but I can't see how to set the source to the AudioPlaybackConnection. My next thought was to create a MediaPlayer and handle the controls/metadata myself, but I can't see how to access the metadata for the AudioPlaybackConnection either. I tried getting the [BluetoothDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice?view=winrt-22621) matching the same phone since I see the properties for the actual device list `AVRCP Transport` and `A2DP SNK` as two separate hardware "devices" making up the phone device, but I have no more luck accessing metadata with the BluetoothDevice. I know Windows 10 supports Bluetooth's AVRCP and can handle metadata/controls [(source)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/bluetooth-support-in-previous-windows-versions), but I'm beginning to think it's under a different device in winrt and I don't have the winrt know-how to track it down.

Comment: Why do you want to create a `MediaSource` object in your window client? The `AudioPlaybackConnection` just receives the data, if you want to control the playback process, you will still have to do it on the phone.

Comment: The Bluetooth spec for music playback includes metadata transfer and remote control of the playback using AVRCP, which windows supports, so I’m trying to display a window that shows the now playing info and allows playing/pausing/etc. The same functionality is built into elementaryOS, which I dual boot, so I’m just trying to get an equivalent on windows.

Comment: So let me clarify the question, now you want to use Bluetooth API instead of `AudioPlaybackConnection `, right? What have you tried with Bluetooth API now?

Comment: I’m just looking to get the metadata/controls - I’m happy using whichever API does that. I first tried creating a BluetoothDevice for the same device ID, which I now realize was the wrong approach. I’m currently making a BluetoothLEDevice and trying to use that for metadata access, but getting the list of services didn’t include the UUID for A/V playback control. I found the device ID for the AVRCP “device” shown by the windows device properties for the phone and tried creating a device from that, but it returns no services. I haven’t had much time to play with it since posting, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've consulted the Bluetooth team about this. But currently, control like this is not supported in Windows at this time. You could submit a feature request about this in the Feedback Hub. Please select **Developer Platform**->**API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request. The related team will check the request.

Comment: Does that mean the AVRCP support is only for Bluetooth peripherals connected to the windows pc? That definitely explains why I haven’t been able to find any info on it. Thanks for your time!